Answer edits not viewed on home page
This question was written on May 22nd.  I marked it as save-for-later because I wanted to come back to it when I had more time.
I wrote my answer yesterday (June 19th; as of this writing 22 hours ago).  Both Jack and KorvinStarmast immediately interacted with my answer, and I got three votes on my answer, so I assume my answer moved the question to the top of other Home Pages, since it was at that point a month old.
I've done a number of edits on the answer since, some responding to Jack and KorvinStarmast's correcting my misunderstanding of the question and some just because I am futzy about wording.  [I typically edit an answer several times after I post when it would be on the home page anyway; after it would naturally have dropped off the home page I try not to touch it unless there is a major correction or addition due]
Normally when I edit an answer, it moves it to the top of the home page for me, but as I look at my Home page at present, I am not seeing this question.  The questions displayed there around where it should be are at 10 hours, 10 hours, then 22 hours, then "yesterday".  If I go to the Questions page, I have to scroll all the way down to May 22, when it was written and when the other answers came in to see it displayed.
Of the question's three tags, I have one watched (dnd-5e) and none ignored.
The question is currently at -4, but I don't recall it being that low when I wrote my answer; it is possible that my answer drew renewed attention to it and it got one or more negative votes in response.  I am wondering if in a similar way that answers of -3 and less are faded out on a question, are questions of a certain negative score or less not displayed on the home page?
Can others see this question bumped to the home page as of my most recent edit?  (As of this writing, 9 hours ago).
Is there some reason I am not seeing it on my home page?

Posts with a score of -4 or lower (-8 on Meta) aren't shown on the home page

@Mithical Thanks - would you care to cite that and add it as an answer?

From this meta.se FAQ:


Questions with sufficiently low score will not show on the homepage when either they or their answers are edited, though they will still be shown on the Questions page. The "sufficiently low" threshold is -4 on main sites and -8 on meta sites


